# Is it possible to observe a number specific dom events within a time frame using Rx for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rxjs, dom-events

I am trying to be notified if a dom event (`keyup`) happens a specific number of times within a time frame.  I see there is a throttle that throws away events within a timeframe, I want to count them.  For example, I only want to be notified if the `keyup` event happens 10 times for a text box within 500ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by saving the timestamp of a click and comparing the timestamp of the click 10 clicks ago with the current timestamp:

(I assuming you are using jQuery here)

```
var timestamps = [];
$('.watched').click(function() {
  var now = (new Date).getTime();
  // add the current timestamp in front of the other timestamps
  timestamps.unshift(now);
  if (timestamps.length > 10 && (now - timestamps[10]) < 500) {
    // do whatever you really wanted to do
    clickedTenTimes()
  }
  // clean unneeded timestamps
  while (timestamps.length > 10) timestamps.pop()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work as requested.  However, it could be done just as easily with an event handler.  I would like to use Rx to handle all the "timestamp" stuff if possible.

Comment: Until now I have not used Rx, yet, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can create observable groups from keyup events triggered within 500 ms with [groupByUntil](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupbyuntil.md) function. Then just count events in each observable group. If there is ten or more events in a group then do something.

```
var keyups = $('#input').keyupAsObservable()
    .groupByUntil(
        function(x) { return x.currentTarget.id; },
        function(x) { return x; },
        function(x) { return Rx.Observable.timer(500); }
);

keyups.subscribe(function(obs) {
    obs.count()
    .filter(function(count) { return count >= 10; })
    .subscribe(doSomething)
});
```